# Is it possible to use Vite to build an nx remix app with proxyConfig?

Tags: vite, nrwl-nx, remix, nrwl, remix.run

I've been trying to set up Remix in an nx project with a Remix app inside it. I wanted to use Vite to set up ports and proxies, but when I configure it, the proxies work but it doesn't serve the main remix app.  I'm hoping someone can share with me a vite build configuration for remix that works.

I'm not including code examples as I'm literally just using an @nx/remix:app default right now.